# How do I use public member variable outside class?

Tags: c++, public

```
class A {
   public:
     int VARIABLE = 0;
};
```

How do I use the public variable inside the function of another class? In Java a public variable can be accessed by using the class name and the dot-operator. Is there something similar in C++?

Comment: Are you sure you're not talking about `static` variables in Java?

Comment: True. But even a public variable without the static keyword can be accessed like that. Although this isn't proper use in Java.

Comment: `class C { public int n; }` – and you want to access it via `C.n`??? Suppose you meant it the other way round, accessing static variables via objects...

Comment: "_even a public variable without the static keyword can be accessed like that [in java]_" - Not through the class name. You'd need an instance for that in java too afaik.

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo Ah sorry, you're correct. I was thinking about the class instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are referring to static members. In C++ it is done as:

```
// A.h
class A {
   public:
     static int VARIABLE = 0;
};


// B.h
#include "A.h"

class B {
  public:
    void foo() {
      A::VARIABLE = 5; // < here
    }
};
```

To summarize comments, the operator you are looking for is the Scope Resolution Operator:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_resolution_operator
- https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/identifiers#Qualified_identifiers

Comment: I don't wish to use it inside class A. I wish to use it inside another class, say class B.

Comment: You can do it in exactly the same way, I've updated the answer

Comment: Do note that you do need to define that static variable in one TU in order to odr-use it.  Or you could just make it `inline` in C++17+

Comment: BTW, maybe you are referring to nested classes, so you can access the super class member from within the inner class? If so, you can't do that in C++, you have to pass the object in some way

Comment: So this "::" is the operator to use? Haven't seen that before ... what is it called in C++?

Comment: @AbdelAleem It is the [scope resolution operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/identifiers#Qualified_identifiers)

Comment: It is Scope Resolution Operator

Comment: @cbuchart Thank you buddy, it worked. One important thing to note was the include of class A.